# Isn't OS dependent on machines, can anyone briefly explain how it is achieved?

Tags: compiler, operating-systems

Certain OS in it's system requirement doesn't specify anything peculiar like in case of [ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) it asks only for "2 GHz dual core processor or better".  If yes, how does it compares with compiled code(C/C++)? I have heard that code compiled in one machine needn't work on another(even if same no of bits). Can anyone shed some light on the basic "flow"? I mainly am focusing commercial desktop and laptop processors.

Comment: "I have heard that code compiled in one machine needn't work on another" How did you install anything on your machine then?

Comment: @PhilipKendall "needn't work" doesn't imply "won't work" :) But I can pretty much guarantee you that code compiled on an AS/400 for its architecture and operating system isn't going to run on my Macbook which uses both different hardware architecture and a different operating system.

Comment: @jwenting: Actually, depending on how old your MacBook and your AS/400 are, they might both be using a PowerPC :-D (G4 in the case of the MacBook and whatever the name of that early PowerPC-based CPU in the AS/400 was before they switched to POWER proper. However, the AS/400 code will use the 128 bit tagged object addressing mode instead of 64 bit pointers, which the G4 does not support.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operating systems are never machine independent, since their goal is to make the machine usable for the users and the application software.

The fact that no hardware requirement is indicated means just that there is a large number of platform supported and with low requirements.

If tomorrow a brand new revolutionary CPU would find its way on the market, Ubuntu and other linux distributions would probably not work on it without recompilation. So a linux porting team would arrange for finding a [cross compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) (i.e. a compiler working on current hardware but generating binary code for another).  They would probably also have to rewrite a small set of CPU dependent functions in the new assembler. This would allow to deliver an Ubuntu for the new platform.

Probably, you would have to chose the platform in the download list to get an executable image which will then perform the installation on your brand new machine.

But looking what happened to M1, it is probable that all this will be finished by the time you’ll buy the new machine.

Answer (score 2):

> If yes, how does it compares with compiled code(C/C++)?

The OS *is* mostly compiled code, mostly C.

> I have heard that code compiled in one machine needn't work on another(even if same no of bits). Can anyone shed some light on this? I mainly am focusing commercial desktop and laptop processors.

There are a large number of extensions such as [SIMD](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005779/processors.html) which can provide higher performance, but only for certain workloads. If you've compiled code *with those extensions enabled*, then it will only run where those extensions are present.

Generally OS distributors choose a target which almost everyone has; the "i686" variant covers basically every Intel/AMD processor made in the last 20 years. Certain pieces of software will then include a second copy of the code compiled with the extensions, check at runtime to see if they can be used, and select the faster version if possible.

Comment: For example, the Linux kernel has a couple of performance-sensitive functions where it will boot with a maximally compatible implementation and then runtime-patch this implementation with a more efficient one based on the features of the current CPU it is running on.